# Mongo: filter documents from multiple collections and merge

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongo and NodeJS and have a use case where I want to get filtered results from multiple collection.

Advance apologies for the long post.

for ex: 
collectionA

```
{
    "_id" : "foo@gmail.com",
    "name" : "Foo",
    "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            -122.420170,
            37.780080
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "bar@gmail.com,
    "name" : "Bar",
    "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            -122.420060,
            37.780180
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    }
}
```

collectionB: Some attributes are not present for all the documents and hence optional

```
{
    "_id" : "foo@gmail.com"
    "AttributeA" : [
        {
            "name" : "AttA_Name",
            "val" : "Coll_B_AttA_Val_Foo"
        },
        {
            "name" : "AttA_Name1",
            "val" : "Coll_B_AttA_Val_Foo"
        }]
},
{
    "_id" : "bar@gmail.com"
    "AttributeA" : [
        {
            "name" : "AttA_Name",
            "val" : "Coll_B_AttA_Val_Bar"
        },
        {
            "name" : "AttA_Name2",
            "val" : "Coll_B_AttA_Val_Bar"
        }
    ],
   "AttributeB" : [
        {
            "name" : "AttB_Name",
            "val" : "Coll_B_AttB_Val_Bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

CollectionC: Some attributes are not present for all the documents and hence optional

```
{
    "_id" : "foo@gmail.com"
    "AttributeA" : [
        {
            "name" : "Coll_C_AttA_Name",
            "val" : "Coll_C_AttA_Val_Foo"
        }]
},
{
    "_id" : "bar@gmail.com"
    "AttributeA" : [
        {
            "name" : "Coll_C_AttA_Name",
            "val" : "Coll_C_AttA_Val_Bar"
        }
    ],
   "AttributeB" : [
        {
            "name" : "Coll_C_AttB_Name",
            "val" : "Coll_C_AttB_Val_Bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

I know Collection B and C schema looks the same but the purpose is different and they have to be different. DB design is not the question so I would appreciate if do not put all the focus on it.

Query:
Assume there is another user (Alan) with same attributes present as Bar that exist in the collection but is not living nearby the location of Bar.

The query I am trying to build on top of these is,

1. Find people living nearby from CollectionA
2. And Collection B, if AttributeA exist and have an element with name: AttA_Name
3. And in Collection C, if AttributeA exist and have an name: Coll_C_AttA_Name

In the above case I am expecting a result as

```
{
    "_id" : "foo@gmail.com",
    "name" : "Foo",
    "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            -122.420170,
            37.780080
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "collectionB_AttributeA" : [
        {
            "name" : "AttA_Name",
            "val" : "Coll_B_AttA_Val_Foo"
        },
        {
            "name" : "AttA_Name1",
            "val" : "Coll_B_AttA_Val_Foo"
        }]
     ,
    "collectionC_AttributeA" : [
        {
            "name" : "Coll_C_AttA_Name",
            "val" : "Coll_C_AttA_Val_Foo"
        }]
},
{
    "_id" : "bar@gmail.com,
    "name" : "Bar",
    "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            -122.420060,
            37.780180
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "collectionB_AttributeA":[
        {
            "name" : "AttA_Name",
            "val" : "Coll_B_AttA_Val_Bar"
        },
        {
            "name" : "AttA_Name2",
            "val" : "Coll_B_AttA_Val_Bar"
        }
    ],
    "collectionC_AttributeA":[
        {
            "name" : "Coll_C_AttA_Name",
            "val" : "Coll_C_AttA_Val_Bar"
        }
    ]

}
```

There is one way of doing is in parts:

1. query Collection A and get the nearby people
2. Loop through the result of 1 and find in CollectionB if they have AttributeA and an element with name AttA_Name and eliminate if they don't match.
3. Loop through the filtered results from 2 and find in CollectionC if they have AttributeA and and element with name Coll_C_AttA_Name and if they don't eliminate such documents.

Is there a way I can use aggregate to build this query as one? I tried reading and trying the aggregate but seems like my understanding is incomplete.

```
        let result = await CollectionASchema.aggregate([
            {
              $geoNear: {
                 near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ Number(long) , Number(lat) ] },
                 distanceField: "dist.calculated",
                 minDistance: 0,
                 maxDistance: radiusinmetres,
                 spherical: true
              }
            },
            {
                $lookup:
                   {
                     from: 'collectionB',
                     pipeline: [
                        { $match : { $and: [{ AttributeA :{$exists: true}}, { [category]: { $elemMatch: { name: “AttA_Name” } } }] }},
                        { $project: { AttributeA: 0 } }
                     ],
                     as: "collectionB_AttributeA"
                   }
              }
         ])
```

If you can explain if this is possible or let me know off this is the right approach that would be helpful.